# Exception <UITextField>, crashing App

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

This is what I got

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do regex matching on object <UITextField: 0x7165730; frame = (121 208; 179 30); text = 'mail@test.com'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7166ca0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x715ed50>>.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c94012 0x10d1e7e 0xbfbb5e 0xb38bae 0xb383dc 0xb37e9a 0x3c04 0x29a9 0x10e5705 0x1c920       0x1c8b8 0xdd671 0xddbcf 0xdcd38 0x4c33f 0x4c552 0x2a3aa 0x1bcf8 0x1befdf9 0x1befad0 0x1c09bf5 0x1c09962 0x1c3abb6 0x1c39f44 0x1c39e1b 0x1bee7e3 0x1bee668 0x1965c 0x1f95 0x1e95)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Sorry if too big, but I don't understand that error, I disabled from .xib Autolayout because that made my App crash in old devices, and my app never crashed in that TextField, is the textfield for emails.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

My Code:

```
NSString *mail = [email.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
if ([self validarEmail:mail])
{
   // code
}

-(BOOL) validarEmail:(NSString *) mail // From internet made for objective-c
{
BOOL stricterFilter = YES;
NSString *stricterFilterString = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
NSString *laxString = @".+@.+\\.[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*";
NSString *emailRegex = stricterFilter ? stricterFilterString : laxString;
NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:email];
}
```

If I comment the IF the app will be ok, if not, will crash.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to provide some code that shows the setup of your text field and/or the regex you are trying to perform.

Comment: My textfield is a normal textfield, I mean just a UITextField from the interface builder.

Comment: paste your code. we can help you better

Comment: @rokimoki: without any code, How can we Identify the error ?

Comment: @rokimoki: I found the issue, added my answer. Please check that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're attempting to test a regular expression on a `UITextField` object when I assume you meant to test it on it's `text` property instead.

### Edit since OP edited Question

Notice this line:

```
return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:email];
```

Your 'email' object is your text field, not your string. Your string is called `mail` (it's passed into the method as a parameter.

Comment: You are right in something, I am using a regular expression to check if my email is right, but I'm checking in a variable, not from the text field, I mean: NSString *mail = [email.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]; then if ([self validateMail:mail])

Comment: It's ok @Jasarien, your first answer was correct.
I mistyped the var, I read it again and I realized. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass the UITextField object through to the regex, make sure that the object you are sending to the regex is an NSString otherwise you will have this error.

You should be using something like

```
NSString *myString = textField.text;
```

and then passing that NSString to the regex.

If you going to be using your regex function a lot you should probably do a check to make sure the variable you are passing is an NSString to prevent any exceptions in the future.

```
if ([myString isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) { /* Code */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with this line:

```
return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:email];
```

You need to change it to either:

```
return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:email.text];
```

or

```
return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:mail];
```